# Initialize child object on a pointer to parent

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, polymorphism

**Motivation for the quiestion**

I'm going through a tutorial for  [Model-View (paragraph Using a model)](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/model-view-programming.html) Using a model in Qt. 
The example shows the following code:

```
//Header file
class StringListModel : public QAbstractListModel

//main.cpp
QAbstractItemModel *model = new StringListModel(numbers);
```

With the following explanation.

> Note that the StringListModel is declared as a QAbstractItemModel. This allows us to use the abstract interface to the model, and ensures that the code still works, even if we replace the string list model with a different model.

I've interpreted their answer like this:

You can develop your project on `model` and if you need to change the underlying data structure you just do it like this:

```
//Header file
class NewStringListModel : public QAbstractListModel

//main.cpp
//QAbstractItemModel *model = new StringListModel(numbers);  Stoped using this, old
QAbstractItemModel *model = new NewStringListModel(numbers);  //complete model change with just a single line
```

**Generalized**

- Is this considered a pointer cast?
- If the child class implements methods which don't exist in the base class, would that pose a problem?

It would be something like:

```
pointerToParent->childMethodNotExistingInParent()
```

- Is this a bad practice? If not, why not?

Comment: `pointerToParent->childMethodNotExistingInParent()` line will definitely not compile. If you need to make such call, you need to cast your pointer to be of the appropriate type. But actually it is not clear to me, what do you want to do?

Comment: @vahancho I would want to see if this is an ok practice, and when should I consider using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, it's an implicit upcast (i.e. going up the inheritance hierarchy, child to parent). That's distinct from an explicit cast, where you specify exactly what output type you expect; it's also distinct from a downcast, where you go down the inheritance hierarchy, from parent to child.
- Yes, new methods/members in the child class are a bit of a problem. They are not directly accessible through a parent class pointer. However, you can use a `dynamic_cast<>()` to try converting the parent pointer to whatever child classes you expect, and access the new functionality that way. It's not an ideal approach though. You're better off refactoring the parent/child class and using `virtual` functions to avoid that.
- In general, storing and using a parent class pointer is not bad practice. In fact, it's often considered good practice if your class hierarchy implements an 'is-a' relationship, because it maintains the distinction between interface and implementation (one ideally shouldn't influence the design of the other). **However**, trying to access child-only functionality through a (suitably casted) parent pointer is dubious territory, as it breaks down that interface-implementation distinction. It's necessary on rare occasions though.

Answer (score 1):

`Is this considered a pointer cast?`: Yes , the pointer to `NewStringListModel` is casted to the base class `QAbstractItemModel`

`If the child class implements methods which don't exist in the base class, would that pose a problem?`: No problem, it is often needed for extra code to be implemented that is not existent in the base class however you can't use it only if keep the pointer to the child class not to the base class (or you implement virtual functions inside the base class)

`Is this a bad practice? If not, why not?` will not compile since `pointerToParent` has the type of `QAbstractListModel` so any implementation inside `NewStringListModel` will not be accessible. You would need to use static_cast or dynamic_cast to be able to access the cild type:

`static_cast<NewStringListModel*>(pointerToParent)->YourMethod()` - this check types at compiletime but it is not safe to use it if you are not absolutely sure that `pointerToParent` is of type `NewStringListModel`

`dynamic_cast<NewStringListModel*>(pointerToParent)` is the safest way but you need to use RTTI which is a compiler siwtch. This checks at runtime weather the cast can actually happen. if not it can throw an exception (i'm not sure about the details of this)

Razvan.

Comment: In this case, `dynamic_cast` should return a null pointer on failure. It should only throw an exception (`bad_cast`) if you're dealing with references instead (which shouldn't be null under normal circumstances, even though it's technically possible).